# File created with File.CreateText() are not in UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

Documentation for File.CreateText() says "Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text."

However, the files created are encoded in Western European.

```
String template = File.ReadAllText(Settings.Default.template, Encoding.UTF8);
template = template.Replace("{{content}}", "éèê");
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(item_path))
{
   sw.Write(template);
}
```

I use this code to generate HTML pages, with `<meta charset="UTF-8">` but the accented letters are not displayed properly unless I change manually the encoding settings of the browser to "Western European".

Any idea why the files are not in UTF-8 format?

Comment: I think the first thing I'd be doing is directly opening the file in a capable text editor and checking the encoding, rather than relying on anything a browser told me

Comment: @CaiusJard I did. notepad++ displays "ANSI" instead of UTF-8. If I use the convert to UTF-8 feature of notepad++, the resulting file works just fine in the browser.

Comment: There could be a problem with your test. Please [edit] your question to provide more details about how you conclude that the file's bytes are not the UTF-8 encoding for the characters "éèê".

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem, here's the code I used to generate a bunch of lower end utf8 chars and write them to file:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1025; i++)
        {
            sb.Append((char)i);
        }

        string fn = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (var sw = File.CreateText(fn))
        {
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(fn));
```

Here's what I see when opening in notepad++:

[image]

What do you get when you do the same?